# Access - Setting Variables with open recordset where clause

Tags: loops, ms-access, vba

I have a 2 input recordsets one with operational data and one with costs associated to the operational data. I need to return for each operational POL the individual cost charge types, in this example 5 types and their costs.

Operational Data

```
Consol
Week    POL        Container Type   Shipment Mode   Container Count     Volume
40      Hong Kong       40HC           CFSCY             1               66.00
```

Cost data (Hong Kong costs are part of a much larger table)

```
Origin Port Currency  Charge Type                      Unit Of Measure  Charge
Hong Kong   HKD       Bill of Lading Issuance Charge   By Container     450
Hong Kong   HKD       Container Seal Charge            By Container     50
Hong Kong   HKD       CY Administration Charge         By Container     300
Hong Kong   HKD       Port Security Charge             By Container     450
Hong Kong   HKD       THC                              By Container     1945
```

The below code loops through the operational data (usually more than one record cut down for example) and then looks-up each cost info and returns cost applicable to the Origin matching the operational POL.

```
Sub CYCost1()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rstCost As DAO.Recordset
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim rstOutput As DAO.Recordset
Dim rstXchange As DAO.Recordset
Dim ContCount As Integer

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("5 - Scenarios 2 - Optimisation - 2 Op Options")

Do Until rst.EOF

TotalCost = 0

'Feed in variables from "5 - Scenarios 2 - Optimisation - 2 Op Options" table
ConsolPOL = rst!POL
ContType = rst![Container Type]
ShipMode = rst![Shipment Mode]
ConsolWeek = rst![Consol Week]
ContCount = rst![Container Count]

If ShipMode = "CFSCY" Then
Set rstCost = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Origin Port] FROM [2 - Rates 1 Origin - 1 Factory Loads - Tariff] WHERE [Origin Port] = '" & ConsolPOL & "';")

Do Until rstCost.EOF

'Get parameter from Cost Tables
CostCurrency = DLookup("[Currency]", "2 - Rates 1 Origin - 1 Factory Loads - Tariff", "[Origin Port] = '" & ConsolPOL & "'")
CostType = DLookup("[Charge Type]", "2 - Rates 1 Origin - 1 Factory Loads - Tariff", "[Origin Port] = '" & ConsolPOL & "'")
CostUOM = DLookup("[Unit Of Measure]", "2 - Rates 1 Origin - 1 Factory Loads - Tariff", "[Origin Port] = '" & ConsolPOL & "'")
CostCharge = DLookup("[Charge]", "2 - Rates 1 Origin - 1 Factory Loads - Tariff", "[Origin Port] = '" & ConsolPOL & "'")

'Get parameter from Exchange Rate Tables
Set rstXchange = db.OpenRecordset("2 - Rates 5 Exchange - Report")
xConversion = DLookup("[Conversion]", "2 - Rates 5 Exchange - Report", "[From] = '" & CostCurrency & "'")

'Calculate Costs
CostX = ContCount * CostCharge
USDCost = CostX * xConversion

Set rstOutput = db.OpenRecordset("5 - Scenarios 2 - Optimisation - 3 Cost 1 Origin CY")
rstOutput.AddNew
rstOutput![Consol Week] = ConsolWeek
rstOutput![POL] = ConsolPOL
rstOutput![Container Type] = ContType
rstOutput![Shipment Mode] = ShipMode
rstOutput![Container Count] = ContCount
rstOutput![Charge Type] = CostType
rstOutput![Unit Of Measure] = CostUOM
rstOutput![CostLocal] = CostX
rstOutput![Cost USD] = USDCost
rstOutput.Update
rstCost.MoveNext
Loop
rstCost.Close
End If
rst.MoveNext
'
Loop
rst.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set rsCost = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

This works but returns 5 output lines for Hong Kong but with the first Charge Type "Bill of Lading Issuance charge" repeated 5 times although it has correct cost for Hong Kong. I presume this is due to using the Dlookup function which returns first line.

I then created the code below to not use the dlookup and hopefully just take the variables from the rstCost recordset but it returns an error item not found in collection.

'Get parameter from Cost Tables

```
CostCurrency = rstCost!Currency
CostType = rstCost![Charge Type]
CostUOM = rstCost![Unit Of Measure]
CostCharge = rstCost!Charge
```

But if I removed the where clause from the rstCost statement to as below

```
Set rstCost = db.OpenRecordset("2 - Rates 1 Origin - 1 Factory Loads - Tariff")
```

the above cost parameters are recognized but it returns 202 records from the cost table and not the 5 in the table just for Hong Kong. So at the moment I cannot loop the rate table to only find the 5 costs specific to Hong Kong.
If you could be of assistance that would be great as have spent days googling this but am not getting any closer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are only pulling one field while you could pull them all without the lookups:

```
Set rstCost = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Origin Port],[Currency],[Charge Type],[Unit Of Measure],[Charge] FROM [2 - Rates 1 Origin - 1 Factory Loads - Tariff] WHERE [Origin Port] = '" & ConsolPOL & "';")

'Get parameter from Cost Tables
CostCurrency = rstCost![Currency].Value
CostType = rstCost![Charge Type].Value
CostUOM = rstCost![Unit Of Measure].Value
CostCharge = rstCost![Charge].Value

' <snip>
```

So no loop is needed.

Comment: Great thanks Gustav. It does need the loop to loop the different cost types and there will be more than just Hong Kong as an entry but yes see your point. It was the rstCost statement where it fell down and that works perfectly as hadn't worked out how to assign the where clause to the variables. This was a real hurdle so now my project can progress, much appreciated.

Comment: Tried to mark as answer but I don't have enough points yet. But consider it answered : )

Comment: Thanks! I'll se what I can do. Have nice weekend.